# Where is $_ being modified in this perl code?

Tags: perl, natural-sort, perl-critic

The following perl code generates a warning in PerlCritic (by Activestate):

```
sub natural_sort {
    my @sorted;
    @sorted = grep {s/(^|\D)0+(\d)/$1$2/g,1} sort grep {s/(\d+)/sprintf"%06.6d",$1/ge,1} @_;
}
```

The warning generated is:

> Don't modify $_ in list functions

[More info about that warning here](http://search.cpan.org/~elliotjs/Perl-Critic-1.115/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/ControlStructures/ProhibitMutatingListFunctions.pm)

I don't understand the warning because I don't think I'm modifying $_, although I suppose I must be.
Can someone explain it to me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both of your `grep`s are modifying `$_` because you're using `s//`. For example, this:

```
grep {s/(^|\D)0+(\d)/$1$2/g,1}
```

is the same as this:

```
grep { $_ =~ s/(^|\D)0+(\d)/$1$2/g; 1 }
```

I think you'd be better off using `map` as you are not filtering anything with your `grep`s, you're just using `grep` as an iterator:

```
sub natural_sort {
    my $t;
    return map { ($t = $_) =~ s/(^|\D)0+(\d)/$1$2/g; $t }
           sort
           map { ($t = $_) =~ s/(\d+)/sprintf"%06.6d",$1/ge; $t }
           @_;
}
```

That should do the same thing and keep critic quiet. You might want to have a look at [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/List-MoreUtils/) if you want some nicer list operators than plain `map`.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing a substitution ( i.e. `s///` ) in the grep, which modifies `$_` i.e. the list being grepped.

Answer (score 3):

This and other cases are explained in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> Here are the places where Perl will
>   assume $_ even if you don't use it:
>
> - The following functions:
>
> abs, alarm, chomp, chop, chr, chroot,
>   cos, defined, eval, exp, glob, hex,
>   int, lc, lcfirst, length, log, lstat,
>   mkdir, oct, ord, pos, print,
>   quotemeta, readlink, readpipe, ref,
>   require, reverse (in scalar context
>   only), rmdir, sin, split (on its
>   second argument), sqrt, stat, study,
>   uc, ucfirst, unlink, unpack.
>
> - All file tests (-f , -d ) except for    -t , which defaults to STDIN.
>     See -X
> - The pattern matching operations m//,    s/// and tr/// (aka y///) when
>     used    without an =~ operator.
> - The default iterator variable in a foreach loop if no other variable is
>     supplied.
> - The implicit iterator variable in the grep() and map() functions.
> - The implicit variable of given().
> - The default place to put an input    record when a  operation's result 
>     is tested by itself as the sole
>     criterion of a while test. Outside a
>     while test, this will not happen.

Answer (score 2):

Many people have correctly answered that the `s` operator is modifying `$_`, however in the soon to be released Perl 5.14.0 there will be the new `r` flag for the `s` operator (i.e. `s///r`) which rather than modify in-place will return the modified elements. Read more at  [The Effective Perler](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/09/use-the-r-substitution-flag-to-work-on-a-copy/) . You can use  [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::perlbrew)  to install this new version.

Edit: Perl 5.14 is now available! [Announcement](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2011/05/msg172326.html) [Announcement](http://dev.perl.org/perl5/news/2011/perl-5.14.0.html) [Delta](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perldelta)

Here is the function suggested by mu (using `map`) but using this functionality:

```
use 5.14.0;

sub natural_sort {
    return map { s/(^|\D)0+(\d)/$1$2/gr }
           sort
           map { s/(\d+)/sprintf"%06.6d",$1/gre }
           @_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The VERY important part that other answers have missed is that the line

```
grep {s/(\d+)/sprintf"%06.6d",$1/ge,1} @_;
```

Is actually modifying the arguments passed into the function, and not copies of them.

`grep` is a filtering command, and the value in `$_` inside the code block is an alias to one of the values in `@_`.  `@_` in turn contains aliases to the arguments passed to the function, so when the `s///` operator performs its substitution, the change is being made to the original argument.  This is shown in the following example:

```
sub test {grep {s/a/b/g; 1} @_}

my @array = qw(cat bat sat);

my @new = test @array;

say "@new";   # prints "cbt bbt sbt" as it should
say "@array"; # prints "cbt bbt sbt" as well, which is probably an error
```

The behavior you are looking for (apply a function that modifies `$_` to a copy of a list) has been encapsulated as the `apply` function in a number of modules.  My module [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aGen) contains such an implementation.  `apply` is also fairly simple to write yourself:

```
sub apply (&@) {
    my ($sub, @ret) = @_;
    $sub->() for @ret;
    wantarray ? @ret : pop @ret
}
```

With that, your code could be rewritten as:

```
sub natural_sort {
    apply {s/(^|\D)0+(\d)/$1$2/g} sort apply {s/(\d+)/sprintf"%06.6d",$1/ge} @_
}
```

If your goal with the repeated substitutions is to perform a sort of the original data with a transient modification applied, you should look into a Perl idiom known as the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) which is a more efficient way of achieving that goal.

Comment: I'll have a look into that idiom but the modification of the arguments is acceptable given my data.

Comment: @Craig => modification of arguments is never acceptable if it is unintended.  What if a few months from now you need to use the sort on a constant array, or an array that will be used again?

Comment: See your point but it won't happen, and I _did_ say I'd take a look at the idiom